# How can i close all forms and processes(explorer) windows when i quit my program?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you Sure you want to Exit. Click Yes to Confirm and No to continue", "WinForm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
```

Application.Exit(); for some reason make me to click twice YES before the program quit.
And It dosent close explorer windows like this:

```
Process.Start("explorer", String.Format("/select,{0}", t));
```

This explorer keep open when i quit my program.

Comment: in your else place e.Cancel = false; or nothing it will work.about your process,have you set a reference to a process object?...if not place one for example  Process p = Process.Start("explorer", String.Format("/select,{0}", t)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, technically these windows do not belong to your application, so they should not be closed.

EDIT, regarding the comment: **the solution provided below won't work, sorry, my mistake :)**

If you really want to control explorer windows you've opened you can collect the return value of the Start method ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx ), and then call the Kill method on each of them ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx ). Remember to check if they still exist as the user might have closed them on their own.

Simple example for one window:

```
class Form
{
//...
private Process explorerWindow = null;
}

//...

this.explorerWindow = Process.Start("explorer", String.Format("/select,{0}", t));

//... (in OnFormClosing)

if (this.explorerWindow != null && !this.explorerWindow.HasExited)
{
this.explorerWindow.Kill();
}
```

Do similar, but with the List. You could also hook up to the OnExited event and remove particular processes from the list, when they disappear (f.e. because the user closed them).

Comment: That probably won't work. The launched Explorer will usually quickly exit after telling the already running Explorer to open a new window. And that already running Explorer should most definitely not be killed.

Comment: Indeed its not working. I had to change this this.explorerWindow.HasExited from !this.explorerWindow.HasExited second the Kill take long time almost 5 seconds untill its doing the Kill. And in the end the explorer window is still open.
                }

Comment: This is working in the Form closing event: foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer"))
                {
                    p.Kill();
                }

Comment: However, it will close ALL explorer windows, not only those opened by your application...

Comment: Ah then i will not use it. So for now i will leave it without closing the explorer when closing the program. The problem is that the user might forget the explorer window open.

Comment: @DanielVest don't mess with explorer.  Showing a folder is a normal operation.  Hiding it from your application code isn't considered nice behavior.